# Redirect all non-model-named urls to named ones in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an app where I'm overriding Rails' `def to_param` method to include the model name like so: `www.myapp.com/1-some-model-name`, however when you go to `www.myapp.com/1` you get the same page with the same content, but these are two different URLs. What's the best way to do a redirect so that everytime I hit `www.myapp.com/1` I go to `www.myapp.com/1-some-model-name`?

Thanks and any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried solutions found [here](http://code.emilientaque.fr/dealing-with-permalinks-in-rails/index.html) and [elsewhere](http://thepugautomatic.com/2009/09/canonizing-pseudo-slugs-in-rails/), but can't get my app to work properly. (I got the error `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)`)

I've make simple solution, but this solution works well enough.

If you are using `to_param` like this :

```
  def to_param
    [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
  end
```

You just add some condition to action on controller looks like :

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    formal = @user.to_param
    if formal != params[:id]
       # on routes : match "/user/:id" => "users#show", :as => :show_user
       redirect_to show_user_path([@user.id, @user.firstname.parameterize].join("-"))
    end
  end
```